# adding bootstrap design to webforms

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have quite old project written with asp webforms (.net 4.0). It uses different webforms server controls like TextBox etc.

There is a design written in Bootstrap.

And the client wants to combine "old projects on webforms" with "bootstrap design".

Is it possible? I see here a problem: webforms server controls generate their own html code, so bootstrap-like design cannot be used directly. The question is - how to deal with this problem, how to overcome this problem?

I do not see a good sollution for this, only rewriting server controls if they doesn't fit bootstrap needs. Are there any widely used Bootstrap-like Web Forms Controls?

Comment: the new .Net web forms uses bootstrap (in its site master and aspx), you could use it the same way by referring the control's 'CssClass' attribute to name to the css bootstrap class. Check bootsrap tutorial

Comment: I am sorry, but what you mean by "new .NET web forms"? Which version you  mean?

Comment: @renathy Were you able to convert ASP controls to HTML and use bootstrap successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first question to ask is what part of Bootstrap does the client wish to use?

**Bootstrap Grid**

- This is probably the simplest part in incorporate into an existing system.  As most existing Web Forms projects use tables for layout, you can take a look at using the responsive tables to control layout of the tables.
- Alternatively, you could look at rewriting the tables using Bootstrap Grid class for a  based layout.

**HTML Input fields**

- For `<input>, <textarea>, and <select>`  input fields, I would suggest that you create a function in your base page that will automatically add the desired bootstrap classes to controls.  By default this would be the "form-control" class.  As a starting point, you could look at doing this during the Page.Init event.
- You can do something like this for buttons also, but your range of options are greater.
- For Checkboxes and Radiobuttons, there really isn't a good way to do this automatically.  You will have to manually modify the HTML for these controls.

Even with the above options, there will be some degree of manual editing on every page.

This is the plan we are currently going to implement on a new project, so I wish good luck.

---

Edit for questions in comments

Modifing HTML for checkboxes and radiobuttons.  What I meant was that at a minimum you will have to add a `<div class="checkbox"></div>` to wrap around the `<asp:checkbox>` control.  Below is recommend html from Bootstrap.

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSuccess" value="option1">
      Checkbox with success
    </label>
  </div>
```

Note, I'm not recommending that you write your own server controls, although that is always an option.

Yes, using Page_Init would be fine.  In terms of code, I would use something line the following

```
For each control in this.Controls
   if control is textbox or control is textarea or control is select then
      control.CssClass = "form-control"
  end if
Next
```

For contorls like GridView or ListView, these generate html tables.  So you can use Bootstrap's responsive table controls for them.

Comment: The diesng actually contains all of these - grid, input etc. fields, as well as checkboxes & radioboxes. Can you explain what you mean by "modifying html for checkboxes and radiobuttons', you mean rewriting Render method or something like this? I am not "afraid" of writing my own html code, add classes to existing controls etc., I am more afraid - that there would be some controls that doesn't work good with bootstrap.

Comment: Morover - can you, please, explain how you plan to do "write function that would add default classes to control like form-control"? For example, if I am in Page_Init, what should I do?